# command line redirection using scanf in my code in C

Tags: c++, redirect, scanf

My code is not reading the file I want it to. Yes, I am using `./a.out < filename` to run it, still it does not read the file. The loop is working, but it is not reading the file and executing what I tell it to. Is my `scanf` wrong?

I have included only a part of the code. There is more in the loop, those are arrays from structs.

```
int main()
{
    char ch;

    int count_e = 0;
    int count_c = 0 ;

    struct customer arr_cust[50];
    struct employee arr_emp[50];
    //char
    //cout << "hi";
    //scanf("%c", &ch);
    while(scanf("%c", &ch))
    {
        //scanf(" %c", &ch);
        //cout << "yp"; (This is a test. it prints out and the loop is continuous)
        //scanf("%c", &ch);
        cin >> ch;
        cout << ch;
        if (ch == 'e')
        {
            cin >> ch;
            cout << "test";
            ++count_e;
            cin >> arr_emp[count_e].emp_id;
            scanf("%s ", arr_emp[count_e].emp_name); //cin >> arr_emp[count_e].emp_name;
            cout <<  arr_emp[count_e].emp_id << " ";
            printf("%s ", arr_emp[count_e].emp_name);
        }
         if (ch == 'c')
                {
                        ++count_c;
                        cin >> arr_cust[count_c].cust_id;
                        scanf("%s ", arr_cust[count_c].cust_name); //cin >> arr_cust[count_c].cust_name;
                        cin >> arr_cust[count_c].cust_bal;
                        printf("%s ", arr_cust[count_c].cust_name);
                        cout << arr_cust[count_c].cust_name << " ";
                        cout << arr_cust[count_c].cust_id << " ";
                        //++count_c;
                }
                if (ch == 't')
                {
                        int e;
                        int c;
                        char type;
                        float amount;

                        cin >> c;
                        cin >> e;
                        cin >> type;
                        cin >> amount;
                        int index_c;
                        int index_e;

                        for(int k =0; k < count_c; ++k)
                        {
                                if(c == arr_cust[k].cust_id)
                                {
                                        index_c = k;
                                }
                        }
                        for(int j =0; j < count_e; ++j)
                        {
                                if(e == arr_emp[j].emp_id)
                                {
                                    index_e = j;
                                }
                        }
     printf("%s ", arr_cust[index_c].cust_name);
                        //cout << arr_emp[index_e].emp_name << " ";
                        printf("%s ", arr_emp[index_e].emp_name);
                        //cout << arr_cust[index_c].cust_name << " ";
                         if(type == 'w')
                         {
                                cout << "-$";
                                cout << amount << " ";
                                arr_cust[index_c].cust_bal -= amount;
                                cout << " $ " << arr_cust[index_c].cust_bal << endl;
                               // printf(" $ %s ", arr_cust[index_c].cust_bal);
                         }
                        else
                        {
                                cout << "+$";
                                cout << amount << " ";
                                arr_cust[index_c].cust_bal += amount;
                                cout << " $ " << arr_cust[index_c].cust_bal << endl;
                                // printf(" $ %s ", arr_cust[index_c].cust_bal);
                        }
   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The file im trying to read is

```
e  5 Elden
c  3 Felipe     55342.51415
e  3 Leonardo
e  1 Yong
c  9 Alessandra 8114.541862
c  6 Marnie     15287.78233
e  8 Kourtney
c  2 Lou        95053.44742
c  5 Numbers    51245.66138
e  4 Jarvis
e  9 Marlen
e 10 Florance
c  1 Devon      56442.27875
e  2 Elliott
c  8 Justina    73723.84849
c 10 Reyna      82946.53205
e  6 Antonetta
e  7 Florene
c  4 Merrill    98281.82784
c  7 Marlana    33252.21805
t 1  8 w 4924.86
t 9  6 d 3220.42
t 6  1 w 127.62
t 9  8 w 5566.7
t 9  8 d 5414.55
t 5  7 w 9422.35
t 9 10 d 1382.07
t 4  7 d 6131.07
t 8  2 w 2362.22
t 8 10 d 5834.48
t 5  4 w 5150.73
t 6  2 d 3795.96
t 1  9 w 3919.45
t 5  2 w 5037.31
t 3  9 w 8129.21
t 8  6 d 1235.67
t 2  4 d 6901.28
t 8 10 d 5599.44
t 6  9 d 1936.16
t 7  9 d 7363.98
```

Comment: Any reasoning why you're using `scanf()` and not `cin` at that specific part?

Comment: Also does it work with manually given input without the redirection? Best you can give us an example what the files content is please.

Comment: Why are you mixing C-style I/O with C++-style I/O? Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it is not reading the file with cin

Comment: @yes2323 You are aware that if you call `scanf()` before `cin` the values won't be read twice unless your file contains that stuff  expected twice? As mentioned, show your file contents please ([edit] your question).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ edited thanks

Comment: @yes2323 Well, now check what happens if you try to do this input manually from the prompt. This will probably shed some light for you to grasp what's going on.

Comment: You are merging both C and C++. Try to stick with any one.